# Car AC is not working

Tags: ac

My car AC was working perfectly and today i took the car (Honda City 2000)for oil change and car wash. The man has blow the air and wash the engine as well. After that my car AC is not working. Please guide me about this.

Comment: As written, there is no way we can answer your question. Your AC was working and now it doesn't ... as stated, there isn't really a question. You are just letting us know your AC is broke. Please add as much detail as possible and we will try to help.

Comment: Paulster is right. I'd check the fuses first and see if they got wet or check that the belt driving the AC unit is slipping. Other than that, we need more information.

Comment: You can't just "wash" the engine without protecting all the electronics.  I did that once and I disabled all my dash electronics.  That man probably shorted whatever that was controlling your AC.

Comment: Yeah Nelson you are right... I went to car electrician, he fitted some wire and it started working. Thanks to all of  you for your concerns.